# Pillow - Image's putdata function not writing anything

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have a code that is supposed to open a file which contains ones and zeroes and write a white pixel for a zero and a black pixel for a one. Resulting in an image with something written on it.

```
from PIL import Image
import math

f = open("SETI_message.txt", "r")
file = f.read()
file_len = len(file)
size = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(file_len))) #makes the size as small as necessary for the file, but keeps the photo square

#create an array that contains pixel information
array = []
for i in file:
    if i == 1:
        array.append("(0,0,0)")
    elif i == 0:
        array.append("(255,255,255)")

im= Image.new('RGB', (size, size), 'white') #create image
im.putdata(array) #insert pixel information into image
im.save('image.png') #save image
```

And yet, the output image is white. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I made two silly mistakes: in the for loop i have a conditional checking if i is equal with an int, but the content is string, and the array needs to contain tuples, not a string of numbers encased in parantheses.

Code now works